# How do I convert a list of times into Unix epoch time in Python?

Tags: python, unix, datetime

I'm currently using this to obtain latency:

```
def time_deltas(infile): 
entries = (line.split() for line in open(INFILE, "r")) 
ts = {}  
for e in entries: 
    if " ".join(e[2:5]) == "TMsg out: [O]": 
        ts [e[8]] = e[0]  
    elif " ".join(e[2:5]) == "TMsg in: [A]":    
        in_ts, ref_id = e[0], e[7] 
        out_ts = ts.pop(ref_id, None) 
        yield (float(out_ts),ref_id[1:-1],(float(in_ts)*1000 - float(out_ts)*1000))


INFILE = 'C:/Users/klee/Documents/test.txt'
print list (time_deltas(INFILE))
```

I would like to convert the float(out_ts) to Unix epoch seconds.

I've tried the following, but have failed miserably:

```
int(time.mktime(time.strptime('(out_ts)', '%H%M%S.%f'))) - time.timezone
```

AND

```
 t = time.strptime(float(out_ts), "%H%M%S.%f")
        print "Epoch Seconds:", time.mktime(t.timetuple())
```

AND

```
d = datetime.strptime("out_ts", "%H%M%S.%f")
        time.mktime(d.timetuple())
```

AND

```
pattern = "%H%M%S.%f"
epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(out_ts, pattern))
print 'epoch'
```

Here's an example of a time I want to convert:

```
82128.668173
```

I'm quite new to Python and any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Could you please paste a few lines of the `C:/Users/klee/Documents/test.txt` file? ETA: In the example you give of 82128.668173, is that a line in the file? And what time is it supposed to be?

Comment: What time/date should 82128.668173 become?

Comment: 090030.262352 - TMsg out: [O] enter order. RefID [F25Q75] OrdID [X1C2760404  ]

Comment: +1 for having actually tried something, and including it in your question! Good luck.

Comment: 82128 is technically 8:21 and 28 seconds.

That is technically another problem. The data I have doesn't have dates. So is there a way to manually input a date that all values will take on?

Comment: When I use: 

timestamp = time.time ()
            print timestamp

I think it's technically getting what I want, but I need to be able change the date to a PAST date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strptime()` functions convert strings to times or dates, so if `out_ts` is a float you will first need to convert it to a string, for example:

```
>>> out_ts = 82128.668173
>>> time.strptime(str(out_ts), '%H%M%S.%f')
time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=8, tm_min=21, tm_sec=28, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> datetime.strptime(str(out_ts), '%H%M%S.%f')
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 8, 21, 28, 668173)
```

However, you will not be able to convert these dates to an epoch time because epoch time is seconds elapsed since January 1, 1970, and because `out_ts` only contains hour/minute/second information, you are getting dates/times in 1900.

You will need to clarify what date you want the epoch time to be calculated for.  The time for this example is 8:21:28, but do you want that for 1/1/1970, today's date, or some other date?

A simple way to add an arbitrary date to your time would be to use a [`datetime.timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object which represents your time, and then add it to a `datetime` object for the date you want, for example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> out_ts = 82128.668173
>>> dt = datetime.strptime(str(out_ts), '%H%M%S.%f')
>>> td = timedelta(hours=dt.hour, minutes=dt.minute, seconds=dt.second)
>>> td
datetime.timedelta(0, 30088)
>>> date = datetime(2012, 2, 13)
>>> full_time = date + td
>>> full_time
datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 13, 8, 21, 28)
>>> epoch = time.mktime(full_time.timetuple())
>>> epoch
1329150088.0
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I would like to use some other date, in the past and I will need to consistently manually change it.

Comment: @eunhealee - See my edit, it should give the info you need on using an arbitrary date, just change `datetime(2012, 2, 13)` in my example to whatever date you want.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused, it gives me this error message:    dt = datetime.strptime(str(out_ts), '%H%M%S.%f')
NameError: global name 'datetime' is not defined

Comment: and AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta', but I am importing the module

Comment: @eunhealee - You are probably getting that error because you have already done the import once, something like `from datetime import datetime`.  If you tried that again it would now be using the datetime that you imported instead of the module.  Make sure that you only have a single datetime import in your entire program, and change it to `from datetime import datetime, timedelta` and this should work.

Comment: @eunhealee - You need to do that on a single line, with commas.  Alternatively you could do the import timedelta first, the problem that you are seeing is that `from datetime import datetime` changes where it will look on the next `from datetime import ...` line.

Comment: I've put it all on one line, and am still getting this problem: 

I've posted everything up on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/dzicVZ71

Comment: I apologize for the continued confusion

Comment: Using what I've placed in paste bin, I've gotten these messages: 

NameError: global name 'time' is not defined
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'

Comment: @eunhealee - You need to take out the lines that have `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.timedelta`, those were only included in my answer as output to show you the result of the intermediate steps.  I've removed those lines from the answer.  Try the following: http://pastebin.com/da3Hp1ey

Comment: When I try what you've posted on pastebin I receive: NameError: global name 'time' is not defined